# How to switch from migrations to dropcreatedatabaseifmodel changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've been building a basic MVC application to begin to learn the ASP.NET MVC framework.

After doing some more reading last night, I learned about "dropcreatedatabaseifmodelchanges" and that sounded like what I want to use while I am in the early development phase.

So to do this in Global.asax I put the following code:

```
public class MyDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SwaggersDB> {

}
```

Where "SwaggersDB" is my database context as follows:

```
namespace SwaggersMVC.Models {
    public class SwaggersDB : DbContext{

        public DbSet<Hostel> Hostels { get; set;}
        public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RoomBooking> RoomBookings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that now, when I add a new property to one of my model classes and re-run the application that the corresponding database table would be updated - however when I query the table it has not been added.

I have also enabled migrations via the package manager, and I was thinking that maybe this has been messing with my Database Initializer.

I have tried using "update-database" with migrations but it says it would result in a loss of data. I really don't care about losing data, I just want to recreate the database each time the application runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer, it will do just that and drop and recreate your database each time. You can use the Seed() method in the initializer to repopulate needed tables. This is good up to the point you deploy at which time you would probably want to disable the initializer or switch to something like CreateDatabaseIfNotExists and then use migrations.

In the constructor of the Configuration() class in the migration you can add:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<COPERSRMS.MVC.DataContexts.ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    } 

    protected override void Seed(COPERSRMS.MVC.DataContexts.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

and your database will be updated with each change. Then you can generate a script to update the previously deployed database that will do a compare from the initial schema.

Comment: I just figured out that when I use update-database -force it updates my schema as expected (good). For example if I add or remove a property from a model class I can run that command and the relevant database table gets updated. However, shouldn't this be happening automatically because in my Application_Start method I am setting the database initializer to be DropCreateDatabaseAlways??? Because that wasn't working and I don't understand why. Thanks for the help

Comment: DropCreateDatabaseAlways is not compatible with migrations. See here http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1689 If you plan on using migrations use MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion for the initializer and  enable automatic migrations or remove the migrations.